# Ajax global events not getting fired on body

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is my code:

```
<body>
<button type="button" id="btnCount">
    Count</button>
<button type="button" id="btnFireGlobal">
    Fire Global Events</button>
<div id="log">
</div>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').bind('ajaxStart ajaxSend ajaxSuccess ajaxComplete ajaxError', function (event) {
            $("#log").append(event.type+"<br>");
});
$('#btnFireGlobal').click(function () {
            $.ajax({ url: 'AjaxService.asmx/HelloWorld'

            });
        });
});
<script>
```

Question: When i bind global ajax events to body they are not getting fired.But when i bind them to document they are getting fired. Please tell me why they are not getting fired on body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These events are designed to be appended on the document object: they do not work on body simply because they are not supposed to !

Example with the documentation of ajaxStart:
http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstart/

> "As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxStart() method should only be attached to
>   document."

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxStart() method should only be attached to document.

```
$(document).on('ajaxStart ajaxSend ajaxSuccess ajaxComplete ajaxError', function (event) {
    $("#log").append(event.type+"<br>");
});
```